# Remove ?id .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

Got here a .htaccess file wherein it only removes.php but I want to achieve also the ?id= will also be removed
(e.g) localhost/new1v2/alumni.php?id=43 will be shown as localhost/new1v2/alumni

Here is my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L] 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^alumni alumni.php?id=43
```

Answer (score 0):

At the top of your htaccess ,add this :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=.+$
RewriteRule (.+)\.php$ /$1? [L,R]
```

This will remove the existing queryString **?id=nm** and redirect your php urls from **/foobar.php?id=nm** to **/foobar** .

Comment: it removes the id?= but it also removes the folder? why? Like from localhost/new1v2/view_events?id=2 to localhost/view_events